# Mostrar ultima pagina por defecto en smart-table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Implemente smat-table con angularjs para mostrar una serie de registros y mi problema es que necesito que la paginación se coloque en la ultima pagina siempre que se cargue la tabla o bien cuando se cambia la cantidad de registros a mostrar con `st-items-by-page`

```
  <table class="table table-md table-lg table-clara table-striped table-hover table-condensed nowrap" st-persist="">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3" class="titulo">Datos</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pointer">
                    <th>Columna 1</th>
                    <th>Columna 2</th>
                    <th>Columna 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="m in mm.datos">
                    <td>{{m.columna1}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.columna2}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.columna3}}</td>                                                                        </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-center">
                        <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="vm.itemsByPage[$index]" st-displayed-pages="5"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="1" class="text-center">
                        <select id="itemsByPage" ng-model="vm.itemsByPage[$index]" ng-options="number for number in vm.pageOptions" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Incorpore la directiva st-persist para captar los cambios que se realicen en la tabla.

```
    .directive('stPersist', function () {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            var nameSpace = attr.stPersist;
            var initialLoad = true;
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ctrl.tableState();
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue !== oldValue) {                            
                    if (initialLoad) {
                        initialLoad = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

Por lo que pude leer en la documentación, la directiva st-table utiliza una función llamada `selectPage()` la cual cambia el numero de pagina a través de un `ng-click="SelectPage(currentPage)"`.
Intente acceder a dicho metodo para modificar manualmente la pagina, pero no e conseguido resultados. Si alguno es amable de ayudarme con esto se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo por mi mismo. Dejo la resolución por si a alguien le sirve.

```
    //Directiva que campa los cambios en la configuración de las tablas y cada vez que se cambia la cantidad de paginas a mostrar, establece la ultima por defecto.
.directive('stPersist', function () {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

            // Metodo que capta si se modifica la cofiguraicón de la tabla.
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ctrl.tableState();
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    //Si hubo un cambio, pregunto si la cantidad de paginas a mostrar es distinta a la actual.
                if (newValue.pagination.number !== oldValue.pagination.number) {                            
                        getSavedState();
                        return;                        
                }
            }, true);

            function getSavedState() {
                var tableState = ctrl.tableState();
                    //Establece la ultima pagina disponible a mostrar. A traves de la cantidad de paginas selecciónadas y cantidad de elementos a mostrar.
                    ctrl.slice((tableState.pagination.numberOfPages + tableState.pagination.number) * tableState.pagination.number, tableState.pagination.number);
            }
        }
    };
});
```